# Combining cause-specific mortality cox regressions into all-cause mortality

Tags: cox-model, biostatistics, mortality, combining-p-values

I only have access to the following dataset summary data and not to the dataset itself.

[image]

In the example, the stats on each line come from a univariate cox regression to model a cause-specific mortality.
My goal is to understand if a biomarker is overall associated with all-cause mortality, which implies that I will have to combine these models somehow.
Possible things to consider:

- p-value -> in the example I only show <0.05 p-values, but pre-filtering might not be needed;
- sample size (n) -> It slightly varies due to missing values (and I cannot use imputation methods due to the lack of access to the dataset);
- effect size -> a given biomarker can be protective or nefarious to different cause-specific mortalities.

Is there a canonical way to deal with this? If not, is there some weighting heuristic? I am just doing some exploratory analysis for hypothesis generation.

The data comes from metabolomics of a cross-sectional cohort, which were then matched to death registries.

Comment: Could you describe the model and experiment behind the figures in the table.

Comment: Say there are only two ways of death: A and B. And we know that some parameter x increases the relative risk of A and decreases the relative risk of B, then we still need to know what the base levels of death due to A and B are. For example, reducing the risk of death due to lightning is not having that much of impact in comparison to reducing the risk of death due to cancer or CVD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an estimate based on the base levels of each risk and the risk ratios of each  risk.

$$\text{All cause risk} = \sum \text{individual risks}$$

With your table you can compute the average individual risks, as you have the number of events among a group of a particular size.

You may also compute how those individual risks change as function of the alanine factor. One problem, is that your table does not show the distribution of alanine. That is necessary in order compute the risks for the different groups.

Example: Say you have a group of $n_1$ smokers and $n_2$ non-smokers among which $y_1$ die because of lung cancer and the risk ratio for this is $3:1$. And $y_2$ die because of diabetes and the risk ratio for this is $3:4$. Then the ratio of all cause death is dependent on the size of $n_1$ and $n_2$.

Example say, with the above ratios you have the deaths

```
Group              deaths + cause
20000 total        200 cancers
20000 total        105 diabetes
20000 total        305 total
```

This could be a situation like

```
Group.             deaths + cause
10000 smokers      150 cancers   
10000 non smokers   50 cancers
10000 smokers       45 diabetes   
10000 non smokers   60 diabetes

10000 smokers      195 total  
10000 non smokers  110 total
```

Or just as well

```
Group.             deaths + cause
 5000 smokers      100 cancers   
15000 non smokers  100 cancers
 5000 smokers       21 diabetes   
15000 non smokers   84 diabetes

 5000 smokers      121 total  
15000 non smokers  184 total
```

In the first case the all cause risk ratio is $195/110 \approx 1.77$, in the second case it is $121/(184/3) \approx 1.97$.

So depending on the number of smokers and non-smokers in the experiment the table relates to a different all cause death risk ratio.

The same principle is true for your case with alanine (and it will be even more complicated in your case since the example of smokers vs non-smokers is a dichotomous division and your case with alanine is probably some continuous distribution).

Comment: So you would not leverage the univariate cox regression estimates? The question was more on how to weight them in a combination.

Comment: @DGB the example shows that you can not know what weights to use because different situations can lead to different all cause death rates. This is a bit similar to the problem of computing a joint distribution when we only know the marginal distribution (which can not be done).

Comment: I am trying to understand your contribution. Under the assumption that all-cause mortality is the sum of all cause-specific mortalities (mutually independent) and that I have the summaries for univariate cox regressions for all of them; wouldn't I know the exact breakdown (cases and sample size of each)? Even if there isn't an analytical solution, there should be a way to score the biomarkers, as, for an extreme example, a biomarker that has a positive association with all cause-specific mortalities, would have to be positively associated with all-cause mortality by definition.

Comment: @DGB in my example I assume that we only know the summary in the first table and the univariate risk ratios. Then I show that this can relate to different scenarios (the 2nd and 3rd tables) of the all mortality risk ratio. So you need to know the distribution of the covariate (in the example 'smoking/non-smoking', in your case 'alanine') in order to know which scenario is the case.

Comment: What about with the additional assumption that the distribution of the covariate is not known, but exactly the same (exactly the same population and sample size, with only the events per cause-specific mortality changing)?

Comment: @DGB without a *know* distribution of the covariate, you can not compute the all cause death rate.